# Working with routes and html (Heist) in Snap

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, heist

I have templates (`*.tpl`) in `my-snap-app/snaplets/heist/templates` (`main.tpl`, `page1.tpl`, `page2.tpl`, `page3.tpl`). 
And here's my `Main.hs`:

```
import Snap.Http.Server
import Snap.Core
import Snap.Snaplet
import Snap.Snaplet.Heist
import Snap.Util.FileServe
import Snap.Util.GZip
import Heist.Interpreted
import Heist

--.......

data App = App { _heist :: Snaplet (Heist App) }
makeLenses ''App

instance HasHeist App where 
  heistLens = subSnaplet heist
```

How can I:

a) Make all the templates available in my web app? Meaning, I want to be able to access `page1.tpl`, `page2.tpl`, `page3.tpl` on
  `localhost://page1`, `localhost://page2`, `localhost://page3`. Should I **necessarily** add a route for **each** page or can I add a route to make them accessible **all at once**?

2) `main.tpl` is a main template (layout). How can I make `page[123]` use  `main.tpl` as a master layout template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Heist snaplet has a function [`serveHeist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-0.14.0.6/docs/Snap-Snaplet-Heist.html#v:heistServe) that acts a lot like [`serveDirectory`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.8.0/docs/Snap-Util-FileServe.html#v:serveDirectory). That will serve all of the templates in templates/ at routes. The haddocks have some more details about, e.g. hiding certain templates that don't make sense on their own.

For composing different templates together, think of templates like functions - you can apply them to other templates, and the result is itself a template. These things all happen in Heist itself, rather than in snap.

The `<apply>` tag performs the function application. The argument is the content inside of `<apply>`, for example, in `page1.tpl`:

```
<apply>
  <h1>I'm a function parameter</h1>
</apply>
```

The function being applied is `main.tpl`, and the parameter is `<apply-content>`:

```
<html><head></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Main template.</h1>
    <apply-content/>
  </body>
</html>
```

The use of `<apply>` and `<apply-content>` perform the function application and compute a full page, which would be available at the `/page1` route.

There is a lot more explanation in the [Heist Tutorial](http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/heist). I wonder if the function-application analogy is useful for remembering more of the heist API.